# Remove inline javascript in jsp foreach

Tags: javascript, jsp

I currently have a jsp page like the following:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<a href=# onclick="javascript:myFunction1();">Submit form with default</a><br>

<c:forEach items="${details}" var="detail">
    <a href=# onclick="javascript:myFunction2(${detail.id});">Submit form for detail id <c:out value="detail.id" /></a><br>
</c:forEach>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction1() {
    document.myForm.id.value = 0;
    document.myForm.submit();
}

function myFunction2(detailId) {
    document.myForm.id.value = detailId;
    document.myForm.submit();
}
</script>
```

For security reasons, I want to remove the inline javascript.  I know how to deal with myFunction1() as follows:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<a href=# id="myDefault">Submit form with default</a><br>

<c:forEach items="${details}" var="detail">
    <a href=# onclick="javascript:myFunction2(${detail.id});">Submit form for detail id <c:out value="detail.id" /></a><br>
</c:forEach>


<script src="myJavascript.js"></script>
```

And in the file myJavascript.js:

```
function myFunction1() {
    document.myForm.id.value = 0;
    document.myForm.submit();
}

function myFunction2(detailId) {
    document.myForm.id.value = detailId;
    document.myForm.submit();
}

document.getElementById('myDefault').addEventListener('click', myFunction1);
```

What I don't know how to do is how to remove the `onclick="javascript:myFunction2(${detail.id});"` with an event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) to each anchor like:

```
data-detail-id="${detail.id}
```

Inside the click event handler you can get the current deatail id value with:

```
this.dataset.detailId
```

In order to select all anchors with such a data attribute you can use:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-detail-id]')
```

Now you can repeat what you already did for the first anchor:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[data-detail-id]').forEach(function(ele, idx) {
    ele.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var dID = this.dataset.detailId;
        console.log(dID);
    });
})
```

```html
<a href=# data-detail-id="${detail.id}1">Submit form for detail id <c:out value="detail.id" /></a><br>
<a href=# data-detail-id="${detail.id}2">Submit form for detail id <c:out value="detail.id" /></a><br>
```